# Why has my PHP and MySQL website suddenly become very slow?

Tags: php, mysql

We're running an AMP server on a FreeBSD server internally.

MySQL 5.0.48
Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3.3

It should be replaced "any day now", but I need to keep it alive and running until then. Its sole function is to host an internal web site. Everything worked okay until last week when *some* pages (not all) on the site suddenly started to load extremely slowly. From a second or so to 20 s.

The source of the problem seems to be the interaction between PHP and MySQL.

The database isn't very big; the largest table contains almost 300 000 rows with a few integers/dates/short texts. And it has at most 30 users, usually much fewer.

If I run all the queries in MySQL workbench, the query that takes the longest time to run executes in 0.3 s. If I add all the duration times, including queries run more than once, the total time is far from 20 s.

I use the internal IP as binding address, and use the same when connecting from PHP.

I copied the site and database to my workstation and, weirdly enough, it's almost as slow on my workstation as it is on the server, though the machine is much more powerful regarding both CPU and memory.

I'm really stuck on this!

Comment: Do you have the MySQL slow query log enabled? That would be the first thing I would check, looking for any particularly slow queries (or slightly slow queries used repeatedly).

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to determine for sure whether the issue is on the DB side, or on the PHP side. If the issue is on the code side, then you need to profile your code. If the bottleneck really is the database, start [monitoring queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html). You need to narrow down the investigation field, until then your question is too broad.

Comment: I'll enable slow query log!

Comment: About the table indexes. I think they are "good enough" if there is such thing... The queries uses those indexes "where it matters". A simple non repetitive query on a small (<500 rows) table is quite harmless, right?

Comment: Determining if the problem lies on the DB or PHP side is a part of my question. It seems both are working fine separately, but something's happening on those three pages. That makes me think it's bad PHP coding that is the problem. But since those pages have worked before and then all of a sudden there is a problem it feels like something's "wrong" with the database. Maybe it grew too big (given the bad coding)? But then again - the queries are quite simple.

Comment: A query not using indexes can land up substantially slower even with 500 records. If that query is then repeated (ie, maybe you loop around the results of one query and perform a 2nd query based on it) then that will hammer the database. The slow query log can help find this, especially if you set it to report non indexed queries.

Comment: We still have not much info to help you really.
The problem is that having no code we have no lead.
We don't even know what this information system is all about.
You talk about an internal website.
Is it protected from SQL injections?

Try a query for.. SQL Queries into tables.
Maybe you got an injection attack.

Really without any more info, the best I can do is a guess.

Check also your php code. Is everything all right on these pages?

Comment: The problem was that the code isn't very pretty or easy to read, parts the mere definition of "Spaghetti code". It's not a trivial task to excerpt intresting parts. And on top of that my new arch enemy, the server, gave me some problem turning the slow query log on (and some other stuff as well, FreeBSD is not my strongest suit and this is a really old and grumpy one). I'm sorry about that. Your assistance was very helpful even though you didn't have enough background data to solve the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

We do not have any code, we do not have any sql related information on this.
So we probably can not give you a responsible reply.
Just guessing, something I hate doing. :)

That "suddenly" seems not all of a sudden to me.
First you must use phpmyadmin to make your life easier and check out your arrays.

Does everything seems ok?
Are there only 30 users?
Is there something fishy?
Is there an array that is super overloaded with records with no reason?

Plus, there is a threshold between performance indifference and poor design when it comes to programming or database design as an array becomes bigger for instance. You gave us not enough info, but check if any algorithm in php loads a whole array on RAM to do something with it. That would be poor design on programming.

For instance, making a FOR loop, nested in another FOR loop to access a whole mysql table and store stuff in an array, consuming RAM, 
then into this nested FOR, if you got another FOR, that access another table using each of the data retreived so you can get other data from another table, based on the previous data, for isntance a foreign key, this can get you into trouble if the arrays grows big.

The bad practice i mention in pseudocode:

```
For i = 1 to m
   For j = 1 to n
      ! You get the data from the one table and store then in RAM into an array.
      ! We get the foreign key values and other stuff here.
      ! For each data you get...
      For k = 1 to w
         For L = 1 to x
            !...you get data from another table using the previously retreived foreign key
             !and store them in an array consuming even more RAM.
            ! Do something
            ! Show results.
         end_for
       end_for
    end_for
end_for
```

As a good practice solution, if that's the case, 
I suggest using exclusively MySQL for quering control. 
Check out also JOIN commands.
For JOIN command read [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

If that's not the case... i really got no idea.

Edit: Made the bad practice example make more sense.

Comment: The PHP code IS poor and the DB IS poorly designed. It's will be rebuilt eventually (process under progress) but it isn't finished yet so I'll have to make the best of it.  (Oups, didn't know enter submitted the form, I'll continue in a following comment if someone by chance reads this before I'm done editing)

Comment: I saw your edit, so I can reply on that.
Yeah it seems strange.Try to monitor CPU and RAM when working your site on your workstation. Try to also benchmanrk if possible some things. You might spot what is wrong and give us a lead.
Check if there are inknown users, like an admin user you never heard of... just in case. Also check out the array contents. Are the arrays as big as they are supposed to be? Many things can happen and cause such issues. Just giving you a few leads to check out some stuff.

Comment: You are the best, thank you for your help! I took one more close look at it all - still didn't find anything really. Then I dodged everyting and went on holiday, snorkling the bluegreenish bays of a mediterranean island for a week. Back in the office chair again, feeling a little less desperate, the problem wasn't THAT hard to spot. Poor indexes in one dbtable. As I first thought, but couldn't identify. As all of you said. I just didn't have THAT dbtable in mind when those specifik pages got ridiculously slow. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! I am happy you solved your case. Sometimes what we need is a little break from what we do really. So half credit goes to your vacation I guess. :)

Comment: As am I. I saw before me having to create a new site, new database and emigrate all data. In a project with deadline: yesterday. Phew.